# magical record importing data and relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm trying to auto import data using MagicalRecord. I've read all the answers that I've found, but do not understand is it possible or not. This is how my data model looks like:

[image]

There are two steps in my app. First I'm getting organization data, and I import it using

```
[organization MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:response];
```

This works fine, later I'm getting participants, and import them using

```
[participant MR_importFromArray:response];
```

this also works ok, only I want to also get the participant relationships added. Json that I'm getting for participants looks like this:

```
(
        {
        CoverImage = "<null>";
        Id = 4377;
        LogoImage = "<null>";
        Name = "Participant name";
        ParentOrganizationId = 2;
        Phone = "123 123-1234";
    }
)
```

ParentOrganizationId is the organizationID to which organization this participant belongs.
So the question is, when importing participants is it possible to set this relationship to already saved organizations? Maybe I need to setup relatedByAttribute or mappedKeyName in my  attributes user info and that's it?

Any guidance is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't say I've used that feature of MR, but have you looked at RestKit which might help you.

Comment: @Wain thanks for the suggestion, I'm doing a lot of stuff with magical record and it really saves me a lot of time, and since there is this functionality I would like to use it, and not import another lib just for that. I know a workaround for this problem, but I'd also like to know is this behaviour possible or not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a great post by Saul Mora called 'Importing data made easy' on the Cocoa is my Girlfriend website. Maybe that can help you.

Comment: @Koen thanks, yes I've already read that, but I don't understand is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 3 days of searching I've finally found it. It is possible!

[This](http://www.ask-coder.com/4193774/perfecting-my-magicalrecord-import) is where i found the solution to this problem.

All I had to do was
In Organization model participants relationship add mappedKeyName "Participants"
In Participant model parentOrganization relationship add mappedKeyName "ParentOrganizationId" and relatedByAttribute "organizationID".

And everything works fine using this.

Comment: With MR 2.3 it's enough to set up `mappedKeyName` (JSON key) and `relatedByAttribute` (`Organization` entity key, this attribute will be used to match against `mappedKeyName` to find the relationship) on `parentOrganization` relationship.